# C: Linked list and writing to a file

Tags: c, file-io, linked-list

I'm facing some problems with linked list and writing it's content to a file.
I wrote some functions that work with linked list (you can insert node at beginning/end, delete node at nth position or search for
an element and then delete it). 
All these functions work properly. If I display the content of the linked list, everything is fine,as expected.
But the problem arises when I try to delete a node and then write the content of the linked list to a file,there are many garbage values.
If I insert a node at the beginning/end of a list, it displays the file properly. The problem arises only when deleting a node.
Each time the linked list is updated, the file is rewritten.Here is the function that writes the content to file:

```
void writetofile(const STUDENT *head,FILE *fw)
{

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Ziadne zaznamy\n");
        return;
    }
    while(head!=NULL)
    {
        fprintf(fw,"%s %s %c %.2lf \n",head->meno,head->priezvisko,head->pohlavie,head->priemer);
        head = head->next;
    }

   return;
}
```

And this function displays the content of a file:

```
void showfile(FILE *f)
{
    int c;
    while((c=getc(f))!=EOF)
        putchar(c);
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

The program is driven by a simple menu using a switch statement, something like this:

```
do
   {
    puts("\nYour choice:(q) to quit");
   printf("a:insert at the begining\tb:insert at the end\n");
   printf("c: delete from nth position\td:search for a name and delete\n");
   printf("e: display file\n");


   switch(choice = toupper(getchar()))
   {

       case 'A':
           pridajstudentanazaciatok(&head,tempmeno,temppriezvisko,temppohlavie,tempznamky);
           rewind(subor);
           writetofile(head,subor);
           break;

       case 'B':
           pridajstudentanakoniec(&head,tempmeno,temppriezvisko,temppohlavie,tempznamky);
           rewind(subor);
           writetofile(head,subor);
           break;

        case 'C':
            vymazzpozicie(&head,poziciaStudenta);
            rewind(subor);
            writetofile(head,subor);
            break;

        case 'D':
            vymazstudenta(&head,temppriezvisko);
            rewind(subor);
            writetofile(head,subor);
            break;

        case 'E':
            rewind(subor);
            showfile(subor);
            break;

        default:
            break;
   }
   }while(choice!='Q');
```

As I said, the file is rewritten when the linked list is updated.

Here is the function that deletes a node from nth position:

```
void vymazzpozicie(STUDENT **head,int pozicia)
{
    if(*head==NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Prazdny zoznam.\n");
        return;
    }
    int i = 0;
    STUDENT *temp1 = *head;
    if(pozicia == 0)
    {
        *head =  temp1->next;
        free(temp1);
        return;
    }
     while(i != (pozicia-1))
    {
         temp1 = temp1->next;
         i++;

    }

    STUDENT * temp2 = temp1->next;
    temp1->next = temp2->next;
    free(temp2);
    return;
}
```

And this function searches for a node and deletes it:

```
void vymazstudenta(STUDENT **head,const char *priezvisko)
{

    STUDENT *traverse = *head;
    STUDENT *previous = NULL;
    if(*head == NULL || priezvisko==NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Nespravny vstup.\n");
        return;
    }
    while( traverse != NULL )
    {
        if( strcmp(traverse->priezvisko,priezvisko) == 0 )
        {
            if( previous == NULL )
            {
                *head = traverse->next;
            }
            else
            {
                previous->next = traverse->next;
            }
            free( traverse );
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            previous = traverse;
            traverse = traverse->next;
        }
    }

    fprintf(stderr,"Student %s sa nenasiel.\n",priezvisko);

    return;

}
```

Can somebody help me?
Thanks.

Comment: "problem arises when I try to delete a node" --> that code seems to be "deleted" from the post.  Post your insertion/deletion functions.

Comment: From the description it looks like the problem is in the function that deletes a node (which is not included in the question). Did you set the link between the node (if any) before the one being deleted to the node (if any) right after the one being deleted?

Comment: @Mtf22 Can you please add the code? How con we help you otherwise?

Comment: I added the code to the question

Comment: `vymazzpozicie` does not check for index out of bounds (if `pozicia` is greater or equal to the length of the list). You _might_ have _undefined behavior_.

Comment: @granmirupa Hi, thank you for your answer, but it still does not work properly :/ As I said, if I try to display the content of the linked list to the screen, everything is fine,no garbage values. The problem arises when I write the content of the list to a file and then display the file. I think there must be something wrong with file input/output but I can't figure out what.

Comment: @Mtf22 you said the problem was on the delate. If that problem is solved the answer is solved. However how do you open the file?

Comment: @granmirupa Do you mean the mode? "w+"

Comment: @Mtf22 Yes, read the updated answer.. I think I got your problem

Comment: @granmirupa Do I have to replace each rewind(subor) with freopen("studenti.txt","w+",subor) in the switch statement?

Comment: @Mtf22 you need only when you delate an element for the reason I explained. But yes you can substitute all of them..

Comment: @granmirupa Thank you, it worked! But I still have to figure out why it does not work if I attempt to search a node and then delete it. (I mean the void vymazstudenta(STUDENT **head,const char *priezvisko) function from my question)

Comment: @Mtf22 what doesn't work? which kind of error do you get?

Comment: @granmirupa I checked it again and it worked as desired (it was my fault). A big THANKS to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This delete function has a main error: **you are supposing that the position you're looking for exist**

Try this:

```
void vymazzpozicie(STUDENT **head,int pozicia)
{
    if(*head==NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Prazdny zoznam.\n");
        return;
    }
    int i = 0;
    STUDENT *temp1 = *head;
    if(pozicia == 0)
    {
        *head =  temp1->next;
        free(temp1);
        return;
    }
     while(temp1 != NULL && i != (pozicia-1))
    {
         temp1 = temp1->next;
         i++;

    }

    if(temp1 == NULL || temp1->next == NULL){
      // print some error
      return;
    }

    STUDENT * temp2 = temp1->next;
    temp1->next = temp2->next;
    free(temp2);
    return;
}
```

---

### **UPDATE**

Instead of using the `rewind()` function I suggest to reopen the file using `freopen(...)` because: if you're removing one element using the `rewind()` you will only overwrite the content of the file for the first N-1 elements, leaving the Nth in the file. Instead, you need to clear all the file all the times.

Comment: You have the same error when trying to delete the last element.

Comment: @CristiFati actually it works for the last element. The problem was if there was no successor of temp1. Anyway thanks for the tip!